# Can a BLE Server identify which component is connected to it?

Tags: server, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-esp32

I have this project, where I need to create a BLE-Server (ESP32) to exchange data with a Laptop/Smartphone etc.... . The code is written with Arduino IDE, using the ESP32 BLE Arduino library and seems like the following

```
void Setup() {
  BLEDevice::init("MIDI_BOX"); // Name of the BLE_Device
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      MIDI_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE_NR
                    );
  pCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());
  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());
  pService->start();
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x0);  // set value to 0x00 to not advertise this parameter
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
};
```

Having this said, when I want to connect my Laptop or Smartphone to this server. It needs to indetify which kind of device is connected to(Apple, Microsoft,). The manufacturer data seems a good idea for me but I don't how to get this information when there is a connection.
A callback fonction is provided by the BLEServer:

```
class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks { //can I here do smth to get manufacturer data ??
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = true;
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = false;
    }
};
```

Can anyone explain to me how it should be done, or are there any better way of thinking ?

Thnx in advance

Comment: You can't know, and should not know, what kind of device (os) you are connected to. The standard is built so that compatibility should work regardless of os.

Comment: That means, it is not possible for a BLE device to know whats the name of the device its connected to, neither the address and manufacturer data ?

Comment: It is possible if the device tells it that information over Bluetooth. You can build software to run on the device which will do that. Otherwise, no, and as @Emil said, it should not work. It shouldn't work because 1) it shouldn't matter to any well built software, and 2) it would make it easier for malware to scan devices for vulnerabilities. Why do you think it needs to identify what kind of device it's connected to?

Comment: Manufacturer data might be present in advertisement data, which only peripherals send. The device name characteristic can be read over GATT but does not necessarily indicate device model or OS. The Bluetooth address is known but that does not tell the OS either. The idea in BLE is to instead advertise specific services using "list of service uuids". Centrals supporting the same specific service can find that device, connect, and interact with it. The peripheral should not need to know exactly what kind of device the central is.

Comment: @romkey I have 2 Leds that needs to be turned on when a BLE connection is established. each one indicates a specific connected device. is it apple or microsoft. Seeing that the bluetooth sig gives to each company member a specific ID, I thought it's possible to get this ID after a connection is made

Comment: No, the manufacturer id is not used that way. What you can get is the manufacturer id of the remote Bluetooth controller using LL_VERSION_IND in the Link Layer protocol, which will give you something like Broadcom, Qualcomm or Intel. But the host OS can generally not be identified in a standard compliant way.